# Adding a Column Chart to Excel Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to make a column chart with the data below. This is part of a user friendly interface, so the first column represents the current case, and in the spreadsheet I have a button that copies the data over to the next column, when the user changes input values so it saves the case they are working on. Note, these two rows in the spreadsheet at not adjacent. The titles (Cases) are at the top of the spreadsheet, and the percentages are a few rows down.

```
"Current Case"      "Case 1"      "Case 2"  "Case 3"      "Case 4"  
85%                  85%           80%       90%           70%
```

1. Since this is an active worksheet, and I am not selecting just the 5 columns, but the user can input several cases. I want the functionality to work so that it will show exactly the 5 Cases (like above), but will also show more cases if/when they appear on the worksheet.
2. I have been trying to use the code below. I want the "Cases" to be on the x axis and I want the Percentage axis to be on the y axis. I am having a problem getting the data to be represented how I want it. I also want each bar on the chart to present the individual case.

CODE:

```
Sub Chart1()

Dim wsData As Worksheet

Dim cht As Chart


Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set cht = Charts.Add

With cht

.SetSourceData wsData.Range("C4:XFD4", "C17:XFD17")

.PlotBy = xlColumns

.ChartType = xlColumnStacked

.HasTitle = True

.ChartTitle.Text = "% Conversion"

End With

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Look into [Charting with Dynamic Ranges](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html). This is one example, there are several more if you search.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have. Certain user friendly enhancements applicable from Excel 2013 may not be available to you, if you have an older version. Secondly Is it is possible to have an extra space for chart data table in the same sheet or use of an extra sheet. Separate chart data table can simplify making a flexible dynamic  program.

Comment: I am working out something to address your requirements and shall keep you posted.

Comment: Thank you for the link Scott Holtzman. 

skkakkar, I have the 2010 version of excel. I could copy and paste the data into a new sheet.

Comment: Do you mean by the sentence "I could copy and paste the data into a new sheet' that you have resolved the problem and do not require any help.

Comment: I could copy and paste the data, but the amount of data that would be copied and pasted would be different each time. I would ideally like to have the graphing option on the same sheet, and not have to copy and paste data to a new sheet. So I am still in need of help! :)